# FPGA board for implementing wireless video

Tags: fpga, wireless, rf, video

I want to  build a FPGA based prototype for uncompressed video over wireless connection with  one box being transmitter and other a receiver (to display). The transceiver speed for HD video (1080) is 3-4Gbps. But it would need an expensive FPGA board. I am thinking of VGA and I guess it needs around 1 Gbps (correct me if I'm wrong).

**What type of FPGA board should I use (preferably cheaper)?**

Also, I would need to interface the FPGA with an RF module. Are there any RF module available for that could be interfaced with FPGA and support 1Gbps speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think reliable 1Gbit RF transmission is the biggest problem here.

Personally, I would take let's say 5-10x WiFi 11n transcievers in 5Ghz band so that you can have multiple 40Mhz channels there without interference.

So, I would start from cheapest FPGA board and single transciever, and once you master that, you will see which bigger board you would need, it's totally depend on huw much logic you want to implement there.

Another way to think is compressing video, or going stright to DLNA (which is basically compressed video over WiFi, standardized).

Comment: thanks. Upto what speed can i get with 1 WiFi 11n transceiver in 5Ghz band?

Answer (score 1):

I usign [A Small Form Factor Software Define Radio of Lyrtech](http://www.lyrtech.com/Products/SFF_SDR_development_platforms.php). You can do many applications for multiples kind of signals, It seems usefull.
This board has three modules: a Digital signal processing module, a conversion data module and a radio frecuency module.
The digital signal processing module has a virtex -4 (I would like other anyone with more resources) and a texas instrument Da Vinci DSP.
As you can see, it has a 1.6–2.2 GHz for high-band RF.
The only problem I see with this equipment is that could be expensive for your budget.
Hope this helps.